# Relational Model

Tags: database-design, relational-theory

I would really appreciate if you could check my answer for a relational model question. I just started learning. So please bear with me and please guide me through the right process.

Consider the following schema for a database that keeps information about business trips and their associated expenses by employees. Italics indiates a foreign key.

```
TableEMP(SSN, Name, DeptNo, JobTitle, Salary)

TableTRIP(TripId, DepartureCity, DestinationCity, DepartureDate, ReturnDate, SSN)

TableEXPENSE(TripId, Item, Date, Amount)
```

Write relational algebra queries for each of the following:

1. Find the names, departments, and job titles of all employees who have any expense item with value “Service Charge” for trips taken to Melbourne last year, along with the date and amount of the expense.

My answer for this is:

```
SELECT Expense 
WHERE Item='Service Charge' GIVING Result1
Result1 JOIN Employee
PROJECT Employee Over Name, DeptNo, JobTitle
```

Is this correct?

Comment: The question includes "to Melbourne" so I would expect the answer would have a predicate on that (most excellent) city. Ditto "the date and amount" part of the question.